# What's different between Dim files() As String and Dim files As String()?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

In this code:

```
Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles("C:/")

Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:/")
```

is there a difference between the statements?

Comment: Back when VB didn't have parameterized constructors, Dim files as String() was obvious. But now with constructors its probably preferable to use Dim files() as String to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two are identical. If you use Reflector, you can see that they are compiled to the same IL:

```
.field private string[] files
```

Answer (score 3):

They produce exactly the same thing - just two alternative forms of declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Both are the same

```
Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles("C:/")

Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:/")
```

Both will declare an array and store all files name in C:\ directory

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a difference.
Example explains everything:

```
Class Demo
    Property X() As Byte
    Property Y As Byte()
End Class

...

Sub DemoCode()
    Dim d As New Demo()
    d.X = New Byte() {}   ' !!! invalid
    d.Y = New Byte() {}   ' valid
End Sub
```