# is "dim x() as byte" equivalent to "dim x as byte()"?

Tags: vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s different between Dim files() As String and Dim files As String()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242000/whats-different-between-dim-files-as-string-and-dim-files-as-string)

Are these two statements equivalent? They seem to behave the same, but is there a difference in the resulting "x"?

```
Dim x() As Byte
Dim x As Byte()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're exactly the same, and you can see that if you examine them with Reflector. They both compile to the same IL.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242000/vb-net-what-different-of-dim-files-as-string-and-dim-files-as-string?rq=1), which is identical if you change `Byte` to `String`.